# jsf page evaluation

Tags: jsf

there's a jsf page with a form:

```
....
<h:form>
 <h:commandLink action="#{userBean.logout}" value="Logout" />
</h:form>
....
<ui:repeat value="#{categoryBean.allCategories}" var="c">
....
```

The `categoryBean.allCategories` is a call to EJB which is based on a `<f:param>` from previous page acquired via `@ManagedProperty`. So when the user clicks on `Logout`, the whole page evaluates, but without the param and there's `NullPointerException`. Is there any possibility how to skip the evaluation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the `rendered` attribute:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty param.name}">
    <ui:repeat value="#{categoryBean.allCategories}" var="c">
        ...
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Alternatively you can also just do a nullcheck in `getAllCategories()` method.

```
if (param != null) {
    // Return it.
}
return null;
```